# Mapfragment findFragmentById always null

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment, mapfragment

I have problems to access the fragment of the map.
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) returns always null. 
I don't know why.
What's the problem?

Thank you!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNombreCentro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:tag="tag_fragment_map" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

And in the activity after the setContentView I try to access to the map, but I receive an exception

```
public class Mapa extends Activity {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ActionBar ab;

private TextView tvNombreCentro;
private TextView tvTelefonoValor;
private TextView tvEMailValor;
private TextView tvWebValor;
private TextView tvDireccionValor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.mapa_centro);
    GoogleMap mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use this way:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            map = mapFrag.getMap();
```

[here is full code with sample:](https://github.com/dhaval0122/DJ-Android-)

Comment: As a note, if you use Android support library to display a map, please make sure that your layout xml file that contains the map fragment should have an android:name attribute value to `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` rather than `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`, otherwise it won't work and keep returning `null`

Comment: Excellent!  it helps me!.

Answer (score 2):

In case your problem is not solved, try this :

As you are using `SupportMapFragment`, while retrieving map, use

```
   GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Also, change

```
   public class Mapa extends Activity {
```

to

```
   public class Mapa extends FragmentActivity {
```

Comment: sorry for the delay. The answer is correct but I don't need to change the extends, only getSupportFragmentManager. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change in the layout

`android:name = "com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"`

by

`android:name = "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"`.

Or, you can use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to get MapFragment but getting null because the device didn't have Google Play Services updated.